# getting dependencies from sdk_aws

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

After updating a project I'm working on, I get the following error when trying to run the `ng serve` command:

```
ERROR in node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/s3.d.ts(12,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/s3.d.ts(908,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/s3.d.ts(1365,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/s3.d.ts(4820,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/s3.d.ts(5096,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config-base.d.ts(1,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'http'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config-base.d.ts(2,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'https'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event-stream/event-stream.d.ts(1,55): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http_response.d.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http_response.d.ts(14,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.d.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.d.ts(145,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.d.ts(281,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
src/app/views/admin/companhia/editar-companhia/editar-companhia.component.ts(15,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'inspector'.
src/app/views/admin/prestadora/ciclo-prestadora/ciclo-prestadora.component.ts(20,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'crypto'.
```

I've run npm install,
 I've tried to get a colleague's `node_modules` directory where the environment is working, 
but none of it worked.

Comment: HI, is this Angular project or NodeJs project, errors seem to belong to Nodejs, just last two are Angular

Comment: @EricAska ok, but my node version is the same version of the project requirements (specific in the package.json).

Comment: I meant that what kind of project structure you have that it's showing nodejs errors with your Angular project ☺ is it Universal or some kind of mixed code base with backend.  Ng serve has nothing to do with aws-sdk. it simply shows that somewhere it's Disrupting some files with aws-sdk. if you have shared package.json probably your tsconfig files aren't configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clean your node_modules first and remove your local package-lock.json.
then :

```
npm i --save-dev aws-sdk
```

if needed:

```
npm i --save-dev stream
npm i --save-dev buffer
npm i --save-dev http
npm i --save-dev https
npm i --save-dev crypto
npm i --save-dev inspector
```